# How to extract a specific date in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I’m trying to extract all the instances in which the dates in my table are ‘03-JUL-16’ but I’m getting zero results. Here is what I’ve tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE purchase_date = ‘03-JUL-16’ ;

SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE purchase_date like ‘03-JUL-16’;

SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE purchase_date in ( ‘03-JUL-16’ );
```

Why am I getting zero results? How can I correct the queries above? What is the answer? Sorry if this is a simple question, I’m new to SQL and trying to learn. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and date functions are usually vendor specific. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: If `purchase date` is of `Date` type - try `'2016-07-06'` and see if it makes the difference.

Answer (score 1):

First, if the date is *just* a date with no time component, then use ISO standard formats:

```
WHERE purchase_date = date '2016-07-03'  -- note the "straight" single quotes
```

In Oracle, a `date` can include a time component.  Actually, regardless of the database, inequalities are a better method for such as comparison so the code works with an without time components:

```
WHERE purchase_date >= DATE '2016-07-03' AND
      purchase_date < DATE '2016-07-04'
```

Comment: Hello Gordon, I am confused because the date has the month spelled out and not in number format in my table. Does it still read it the same if I use the number of the month instead of the abbreviated spelling?

Comment: @JohnC578 . . . In the database, dates should be stored using a native `date` data type, not a string.  They values can be displayed using various different formats *depending on the database* and on the client tool.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming since you tagged Oracle, you are using an Orcale DB. That being true, you could also use the TO_DATE function to help.

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE purchase_date = TO_DATE('03/07/16','DD/MM/YY')
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hello Elliot, unfortunately this did not work. It resulted in zero rows however I know this date exists within my table.